# PostgreSQL - counting rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider the following which lists the authors of some books:

```
Table

name     bookid
---------------
Alan        1
Bob         1
Charlie     2
David       2
```

I want to find out the how many co-authors a person has over his entire book-line. e.g., if Alan has written two books, one with Bob and another one with Charlie+David, then his total co-author count should be 3.

What I tried (but not working):

```
select t1.name, count(t2.name)
from table t1, table t2 
where t1.bookid = t2.bookid
```

Any help guys? Much appreciated.

Comment: select t1.name, count(t2.name) from table t1, table t2 where t1.bookid=t2.bookid

Comment: Homework assignment? This is [tutorial level material](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.name, count(t2.name)
from table1 t1, table1 t2 
where t1.bookid = t2.bookid 
and t1.name != t2.name
group by t1.name
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6c2b2/2)

Comment: Maybe `count(distinct t2.name)`? The same author may appear many times.

Comment: Also it is better to do a `left join`. An author may not have any co-authors.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT name, count(*) as cnt
FROM table
GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: it will return always 1 as count in this example

Comment: For you table this will return 1 as count because you have not same author for two book. But if you add new row with name Alan and bookid = 3, Alan will have 2 as count column.

Comment: alan and bob are two authors for the same book. charlie and david too.

Comment: You right, I am not correctly understand question :(